# Filter Data from dataset that is passed to textbox

Tags: vb.net, filter, dataset, cell

I am iterating through columns in a datagridview in vb net and passing the
values to a textbox. I need to be able to filter out the emails which are in Cell(4), so that there are no duplicate emails for any single customer.

I have no idea of how to do this using a dataset.

```
EmailTableAdapter.Fill(Me.EmailDataset.Email)

  Dim r As String = String.Empty
        For i As Integer = 0 To Me.EmailDataGridView.RowCount - 1
            r = r & EmailDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value.ToString & "  -  " & EmailDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value.ToString & vbNewLine
        Next
        TextBox2.Text = (r)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to filter out rows with duplicate values in Cells(4) would be to iterate through the grid rows, stuffing items into a Dictionary using Cells(4) values as the Key, and then iterate through the Dictionary to build your "r" string. Such a solution would look something like this:

```vb
EmailTableAdapter.Fill(Me.EmailDataset.Email)

Dim EmailDict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
For i As Integer = 0 To Me.EmailDataGridView.RowCount - 1
    If Not EmailDict.ContainsKey(EmailDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value.ToString) Then
        EmailDict.Add(EmailDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value.ToString, EmailDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value.ToString)
    End If
Next

Dim EmailPair As KeyValuePair(Of String, String)
Dim r As String = String.Empty
For Each EmailPair In EmailDict
    r &= EmailPair.Value & "  -  " & EmailPair.Key & vbNewLine
Next

TextBox2.Text = (r)
```